# PHP CLI -f array union stops after 5000 elements

Tags: php, rest, php-curl

I'm trying to parse an API response that can have thousands of results so it provides a `@odata.nextLink`. I want to return all of the results in an array so after I make a curl request that has a `nextLink`, I use php aray union to add to the previous array with the result

```
$result_array = $api_response['value']; //store initial response

while (array_key_exists('@odata.nextLink', $api_response)) {

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
       CURLOPT_URL => $api_response['@odata.nextLink'],
       (more options)...
    )):

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
        $api_response = json_decode($response, TRUE);
        $result_array = $result_array + $api_response['value'];
    }
}
```

A response looks like this

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https:/api.com/v1/query","value":[
    {
      "Sku":"ABC","ID":123
    },
    (more records)...
  ],"@odata.nextLink":"https://api.com/v1/query&$skip=200"
}
```

array looks like this with `print_r`

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Sku] => abc
            [ID] => 123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Sku] => efg
            [ID] => 456
        )
    (more results)...

)
```

However, it stops adding elements to the array after 5000. I execute the script file from `php -f` for testing. I try `ini_set('memory_limit', '1000M');` like suggested to overcome memory limit but it doesn't help. Is this some sort of limitation for the PHP CLI? On a live server would this still happen? Eventually I'd like to make another curl request on each product id in a large data set (probably in a batch) to see if the api can handle it.

Edit: When I meant set up curl, I was changing the curl request to next link. I added the change for clarification and show that it doesn't loop infinitely.

Edit 2: OK so I have a better deal of what's happening. The API returns the `value` as a 2d array, each inner array is a different record. It returns 100 results a few times until it serves 5000. The array key resets each time. The after setting the initial `$result_array` is set to first 100 results, the plus operator doesn't append the next 100 since they are the same keys. Once API starts returning 5000 results, it appends from index 100 to 4999. Subsequent requests don't add more like previously. Is there a an array function in php that can append multidimensional arrays to each other like + does with one dimensional arrays? I could do a `foreach` to append properly but it seems tedious if there's already a built-in method.

Comment: PHP doesn't just "stop" it failed with an error or it finished. Find out which.

Comment: Did you also set a custom timeout? That may be your issue.

Comment: Apply this to the beginning of your script to see what is going on: `register_shutdown_function(function(){var_dump(error_get_last());});`

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @mopsyd @AbraCadaver I tried adding your lines but no errors show.  If it makes any difference, my file calls a function from another file. Also I set `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60` since it took some time for api to respond back.

Comment: The code I provided you will output the string `NULL` if there are no errors. If you are not seeing at least that, then your `while` loop is not terminating because it lacks a break condition that resolves to `true`. If you are seeing that and are not getting the result you want, then you have an incorrect break condition, because it is resolving to `true` prior to completion, and it is not parsing the full set of values. Perhaps try using a `foreach` instead of `while`.

Comment: So I see `NULL` at the end. How would I use a `foreach`? I don't know if the response will have a `@odata.nextLink` which is why I use `array_key_exist`. The last result won't have that array key. I debugged the code and indeed it does keep making the calls until theres no `nextLink`. For some reason, the union isn't appending the `value` array.

Answer (score 0):

one thing to note about using + with arrays is if the elements keys are the same or the array is not explicitly keyed, no elements will be added.

for example:

```
var_dump(['a','b','c'] + ['d','e','f']); 
/* outputs
array(3) {
  [0]=> "a"
  [1]=> "b"
  [2]=> "c"
}
*/

print_r([0=>'a',1=>'b',2=>'c'] + [3=>'d',4=>'e',5=>'f']);
/* outputs
array(6) {
  [0]=>"a"
  [1]=>"b"
  [2]=>"c"
  [3]=>"d"
  [4]=>"e"
  [5]=>"f"
} */
```

if you want to add elements with same keys, use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
print_r(array_merge(['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f']));
/* outputs
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
    [5] => f
)
*/
```

Comment: I thought it was the opposite. Regardless, I tried that before and I only get an array of 100. The response has same keys as any previous 100.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and I feel silly.

```
foreach ($api_response['value'] as $key) {
    array_push($result_array, $key);
}
```

Not the most elegant but it works. Still I wonder if there's a built-in function for this.